# Applicative permutation to generate knight moves

Tags: haskell, combinatorics, chess, monads

I want to understand Haskell better by trying to stretch possibilities of Functor, Applicative, and Monad as much as possible and study how they behave. So in [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads) there's an exercise to generate all possible moves for a knight from a given position on chessboard:

> ```
> moveKnight :: KnightPos -> [KnightPos]  
> moveKnight (c,r) = filter onBoard  
>     [(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1)  
>     ,(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)  
>     ]  
>     where onBoard (c,r) = c `elem` [1..8] && r `elem` [1..8]
> ```

Now I thought to myself, wait a second, I can actually generate that list `[(c+2,r-1),(c+2,r+1),(c-2,r-1),(c-2,r+1),(c+1,r-2),(c+1,r+2),(c-1,r-2),(c-1,r+2)]` instead of hardcoding it. So this is how I did it with list comprehensions:

```
invert x
  | x == 1 = 2
  | x == 2 = 1
  | otherwise = 0

moves = [(c `f` a, r `g` (invert a)) |
         c <- [6],
         r <- [2],
         f <- [(+), (-)],
         g <- [(+), (-)],
         a <- [1, 2]]

-- generates: [(7,4),(8,3),(7,0),(8,1),(5,4),(4,3),(5,0),(4,1)]
```

So the above works correctly, but the code looks ugly. Because every list comprehension is equivalent to a lift, the above code could be rewritten with `liftA5`:

```
liftA5 :: Applicative g => (a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f) -> g a -> g b -> g c -> g d -> g e -> g f
liftA5 f a b c d e = f <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> d <*> e

liftA5 (\c r f g a -> (c `f` a, r `g` (invert a))) [6] [2] [(+), (-)] [(+), (-)] [1,2]
```

My questions are:

- Are there any way to generate the above list in a more elegant way?
- How to generalize it to arbitrary possible permutations? (So that my code could parametrized and not fixed to just numbers 1 and 2, or just + and -, etc)
- What intuitions, insights and lessons can I get from this exercise?

I know that this is a massively contrived situation, but they serve me as an exercise to understand the language better.

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern matching you can write:

```
invert 1 = 2
invert 2 = 1
invert n = 0 -- Error would be better in my opinion
```

---

You can inline 6 and 2 instead of taking them from a single item list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "more elegant", but there is this:

```
moveKnight start =
  filter onBoard $
  f (f ((,) <$> [(+),(-)] <*> [(+),(-)]) <*> [start]) <*> [(1,2), (2,1)]
  where
    onBoard = (`elem` ((,) <$> [1..8] <*> [1..8]))
    f = map $ uncurry (***)
```

That needs a better name for `f` of course. The `[(1,2), (2,1)]` can be generated by `(filter (uncurry (/=)) $ (,) <$> [1,2] <*> [1,2])`, but that seems overkill.

Comment: I would argue that such use of Applicatives & Arrows is far from elegant, as elegance rests on simplicity & clarity.

Comment: Perhaps; one could also argue though that the original solution brought in unnecessary monad machinery, and it's more elegant to avoid the implicit imperative ordering monadic style enforces. It's probably a losing argument, but I think it's worth considering.

Comment: I agree that is it "more elegant", just not objectively elegant. I remember recently toying with an Applicative solution for knight's move generation on and off for about a week before I settled on a different solution I thought was more elegant. I'll see if I can find it and post it as an answer.